# BSF Assertion Response Failure Message

Tags: jmeter

can any one help me to print the failure message when using BSF assertion with Javascript in Jmeter similar to Failure message function in beanshell assertion?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can use the logger from JMeter and its log levels e.g. debug, info etc

You can try:

```
log.err("Your error message");
```

Comment: I have to print the assertion error to the ant html report where I need to print entire response for failed requests. Can you please help me for the same